# Do you have any suggestions for a Machine Learning method that may actually learn to distinguish these two classes?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, svm

I have a dataset that overlaps a lot. So far my results with SVM are not good. Do you have any recomendations for a model that may be able to differ between these 2 datasets?

[Scatter plot from both classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjPmq.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to fit the dataset by interpolation of one of the classes and predicting the other one otherwise. The problem with this approach is though, that it will not generalize well. The question you have to ask yourself is, if you can predict the class of a point given its attributes. If not then every ML algorithm will also fail to do so.

Then the only reasonable thing you can do is to collect more data and more attributes for every point. Maybe by adding a third dimension you can seperate the data more easily.

Comment: Hi Thomaz, thanks a lot for you comment, we may have other attributes that may help on separating both classes. Amount of data is an issue, and the 2 classes are also very unbalanced. I can notice by their histograms that their values overlap a lot, so I don't think any method will be able to separate them.

Comment: I take issue with your phrase "if *you* can predict".  Machine learning (and deep learning especially) are there, in part, to find differentiations that the human mind will *not* find in reasonable time, or at all.

Comment: Especially deep learning on images is doing tasks we know how to do instantly. Object classification, NLP and semantic segmentation are just three examples. Naturally  we can not do this on a scale that matters manually, but still most ML tasks are solved by experts for a single point in a reasonable time. For a more indepth explanation by Andrew Ng: https://hbr.org/2016/11/what-artificial-intelligence-can-and-cant-do-right-now

Answer (score 0):

If the data is overlapping so much, both should be of the same class, but we know they are not. So, there is/are some feature(s) or variable(s) that is/are separating these data points into two classes. Try to add more features for data.

And sometimes, just transforming the data into a different scale can help.

Both the classes need not be equally distributed, as skewed data distribution can be handled separately.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, what is your criterion for "good results"?  What style of SVM did you use?  Simple linear will certainly fail for most concepts of "good", but a seriously convoluted Gaussian kernel *might* dredge something out of the handfuls of contiguous points in the upper regions of the plot.

I suggest that you run some basic statistics on the data you've presented, to see whether they're actually as separable as you'd want.  I suggest a T-test for starters.

If you have other dimensions, I strongly recommend that you use them.  Start with the greatest amount of input you can handle, and reduce from there (principal component analysis).  Until we know the full shape and distribution of the data, there's not much hope of identifying a useful algorithm.

That said, I'll make a pre-emptive suggestion that you look into spectral clustering algorithms when you add the other dimensions.  Some are good with density, some with connectivity, while others key on gaps.